# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Duplicate states in queue'

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm working on a project that use `UISlideViewController`. I know that this may be a duplicate question but non of the posts before about this topic helped me. I have a specific problem, as I managed to understand. My app crashes on this block. I have read before, it's important to put all work with the UI in the main thread. This is the code:

```
pageViewController.setViewControllers([viewController],
                    direction: direction,
                    animated: animated,
                    completion: { completed in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
 ...
```

The error that I get is next:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Duplicate states in queue'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183fd1900 0x18363ff80 0x183fd17d0 0x18494499c 0x1894dc9f4 0x1894dcdec...)
```

Testing it further I also get this error on the same line of code:

```
    *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'No view controller managing visible view <UITableView: 0x12744aa00;
frame = (0 0; 375 515);
    clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; 
    gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12836cf60>; 
    layer = <CALayer: 0x1286226b0>;
    contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {375, 291}>'
```

The bug is very hard to reproduce. One literally needs to touch and scroll multiple times on UIPageViewController to get this crash.
Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Did you check putting breakpoints inside the block ?

Comment: Yes I did... If user handles normal with UIPageViewController crash won't happen and the breakpoint is checked. I updated my question with a another error that occurs.

Comment: when you are setting the tableview and delegate the class object is getting deallocated

Comment: Can you please elaborate that? I'm not sure if I fully understand it...

Comment: "No view controller managing visible view" - means the tableview 's viewcontroller is getting deallocated when tableview is using its delegate or datasource

Comment: Facing same issue, do you found solution ?

Comment: No, I haven't found solution for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` code inside of a `dispatch_async block`. It worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749239

Comment: This solution doesn't work for the error. I'm also facing this same error and have already added DispatchQueue.main.async still getting the error.

Comment: @Raymond did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @Raymond did you find any solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I have found solution. I haven't seen this error recently so can't be sure if I've fix or not.