# UIPageViewController transition bugged if animation starts in the meanwhile

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a strange behaviour in my app using a `UIPageViewController`.
The layout of my app is a PageViewController (camera roll like) with a ads banner on bottom.

The banner's container starts as hidden and, when the ad gets loaded, i set the `isHidden=false` with an animation.

My problem is that when the banner gets into the screen it breaks the UIPageViewController transition if in progress as shown in this video:

[image]

I made a new project that reproduces the error very easy with a few lines, you can checkout it in [GITHUB](https://github.com/HeysonDev/UIPageViewControllerTransitionErrorExample): You just need to spam the "Next" button until the banner gets loaded. It also can be reproduced by swipping the `PageViewController` but is harder to reproduce.

The full example code is:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController,UIPageViewControllerDelegate,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var constraintAdviewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!
    weak var pageViewController : UIPageViewController?

    @IBOutlet weak var containerAdView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var adView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerPager: UIView!

    var currentIndex = 0;
    var clickEnabled = true

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pageVC = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)
        pageViewController = pageVC
        pageVC.delegate = self
        pageVC.dataSource = self
        addChildViewController(pageVC)
        pageVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        containerPager.addSubview(pageVC.view)
        pageVC.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        pageVC.view.frame = containerPager.bounds
        pushViewControllerForCurrentIndex()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.containerAdView.isHidden = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+4) {
            self.simulateBannerLoad()
        }

    }

    @IBAction func buttonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard clickEnabled else {return}
        currentIndex -= 1;
        pushViewControllerForCurrentIndex()

    }

    @IBAction func button2Clicked(_ sender: Any) {
        guard clickEnabled else {return}
        currentIndex += 1;
        pushViewControllerForCurrentIndex()
    }


    private func simulateBannerLoad(){
        constraintAdviewHeight.constant = 50
        pageViewController?.view.setNeedsLayout()
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                       delay: 0, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: {
                        self.containerAdView.isHidden = false
                        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                        self.pageViewController?.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })

    }

    //MARK: data source

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return getViewControllerForIndex(currentIndex+1)
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        return getViewControllerForIndex(currentIndex-1)
    }

    func getViewControllerForIndex(_ index:Int) -> UIViewController? {
        guard (index>=0) else {return nil}
        let vc :UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: .main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "pageTest")
        vc.view.backgroundColor = (index % 2 == 0) ? .red : .green
        return vc
    }

    func pushViewControllerForCurrentIndex() {
        guard let vc = getViewControllerForIndex(currentIndex) else {return}
        print("settingViewControllers start")
        clickEnabled = false
        pageViewController?.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: { finished in
            print("setViewControllers finished")
            self.clickEnabled = true
        })
    }
}
```

**Note:** Another unwanted effect is that the last completion block when the bug occurs does not get called, so it leaves the buttons disabled:

```
    func pushViewControllerForCurrentIndex() {
        guard let vc = getViewControllerForIndex(currentIndex) else {return}
        print("settingViewControllers start")
        clickEnabled = false
        pageViewController?.setViewControllers([vc], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: { finished in
            print("setViewControllers finished")
            self.clickEnabled = true
        })
    }
```

**Note2**: The banner load event is something I can't control manually. Due to the library used for displaying ads its a callback in the main thread that can happen in any moment. In the sample proyect this is simulated with a `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter:` call

How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: i think it may be a thread problem. try makig tha animation on the main thread

Comment: I'm making the animation in the main thread (Thread.isMainThread == true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What wrong?**

Layout will interrupt animation.

**How to prevent?**

Not change layout when pageViewController animating.

When the ad is loaded:
Confirm whether pageViewController is animating, if so, wait until the animation is completed and then update, or update

**Sample:**

```
    private func simulateBannerLoad(){
        if clickEnabled {
            self.constraintAdviewHeight.constant = 50
        } else {
            needUpdateConstraint = true
        }
    }
    var needUpdateConstraint = false
    var clickEnabled = true {
        didSet {
            if clickEnabled && needUpdateConstraint {
                self.constraintAdviewHeight.constant = 50
                needUpdateConstraint = false
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For us, it was due to a device rotation causing a layout pass at the same time as an animation to a new view controller. We could not figure out how to stop the layout pass in this situation.

This worked for us:

```
let pageController = UIPageViewController()

func updatePageController() {
    pageController.setViewControllers(newViewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: {[weak self] _ in
        // There is a bug with UIPageViewController where a layout pass during an animation
        // to a new view controller can cause the UIPageViewController to display the old and new view controller
        // In our case, we can compare the view controller `children` count against the the `viewControllers` count
        // In other cases, we may need to examine `children` more closely against `viewControllers` to see if there discrepancies.
        // Since this is on the animation callback we need to dispatch to the main thread to work around another bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749239/2191796
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else {return}
            
            if self.pageController.children.count != self.pageController.viewControllers?.count {
                self.pageController.setViewControllers(self.pageController.viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    })
}
```