# UIPageViewController Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3, DispatchMainQueue doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift4, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using pageViewController inside my app which works fine when its parent view is pushed on navigation stack, but when its parent is being displayed inside a window, then it crashes while navigating to the next viewController with the exception.

> Invalid parameter not satisfying: [views count] == 3

Configuration is:

```
transitionStyle = .scroll
setViewControllers(...animated:true...)
```

There are already many questions about this on StackOverflow.

[Crash1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000712/pageviewcontroller-setviewcontrollers-crashes-with-invalid-parameter-not-satisf) provides two solutions but one doesn't apply in my case. (textField) & other doesn't work (DispathMainQueue).

[Crash2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20004310/invalid-parameter-exception-thrown-by-uiqueuingscrollview), I've tried setting the view controller inside `DisptachMainQueue` but it doesn't work, setting `setViewControllers(...animated:false...)` and `transitionStyle: .pageCurl` works but is there any other way with `animated:true` and `transitionStyle: .scroll` using Swift 4?

Comment: @the4kman I've already provided the link to this that answer, that doesn't help...

Comment: I'm sorry about that, the title misled me. Retracted my close vote. The new title you provided is much better.